# Can a REST API return multiple resources as one single compound resource?

Tags: rest, web-api, resources

I'm in the progress of creating a REST API and currently, I'm encountering the following problem:

- `Foo` is the first resource. CRUD operations can be applied via the `/foo/` URI.
- `Bar` is the second resource. CRUD operations can be applied via the `/bar/` URI.
- Every `Foo` is associated with zero or one `Bar`. The reason why I don't treat `Bar` as a subresource of `Foo` is because the same `Bar` instance can be shared between mutiple `Foo`s. So I figured it's better to access it via an independent URI instead of `/foo/[id]/bar`.

My problem is that in a significant amount of cases, clients which ask for a `Foo` instance are also interested in the associated `Bar` instance. Currently, this means that they have to perform two queries instead of one. I want to introduce a way that allows to get both objects with one single query, but I don't know how to model the API for doing that. What I came up with so far:

- I could introduce a query parameter similar to this: `/foo/[id]?include_bar=true`. The problem with this approach is that the resource representation (e.g. the JSON structure) of the response would need to look different (e.g. a container such as `{ foo: ..., bar: ... }` instead of just a serialized `Foo`), which makes the `Foo` resource endpoint "heterogeneous". I don't think that's a good thing. When querying `/foo`, clients should always get the same resource representation (structure), regardless of query parameters.
- Another idea is to introduce a new read-only endpoint, e.g. `/fooandbar/[foo-id]`. In this case, it's no problem to return a representation like `{ foo: ..., bar: ... }`, because then it's just the "official" representation of the `fooandbar` resource. However, I don't know if such a helper endpoint is really RESTful (this is why I wrote "can" in the title of the question. Of course it's technically possible, but I don't know if it's a good idea).

What do you think? Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: What's the term for the relationship between Foo and Bar?  Could you say that Bar is a parent of Foo?

Comment: A `Bar` cannot exist without being associated to a `Foo`. However, as I wrote above, it's possible that multiple `Foo`s share the same `Bar`. It should be possible to create a `Foo` without a `Bar` associated, so I don't think `Bar` should be treated as parent.

Comment: I think you are experiencing some of the problems I have had by translating directly domain model relationships into URIs and equating *resources* to *domain entities*. It might interest [REST APIs must be hypertext-driven](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven). Special attention to the 4th point

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [level 3](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) REST API would return you a `Foo` and also a link indicating the related `Bar`.

```
GET /foo/123
<foo id="123">
  ..foo stuff..
  <link rel="bar" uri="/bar/456"/>
</foo>
```

You could then add a "drill down" feature to your API which allows the navigation of links;

```
GET /foo/123?drilldown=bar
<foo id="123">
  ..foo stuff..
  <link rel="bar" uri="/bar/456">
    <bar id="456">
      ..bar stuff...
    </bar>
  </link>
</foo>
```

The drill down feature would sit in front of the APIs and intercept responses. It would make the drill down calls and fill in the details before handing the response back to the caller.

This is a pretty common thing in level 3 REST as it much reduces client/server chattiness over slow http. The company I work for produces a level 3 REST API with exactly this feature.

**Update:**
For what its worth, here's how it might look in JSON. This is how our API would structure it. Note that you can nest your drill downs to pull links of links etc.

```
GET /foo/123?drilldown=bar

{
  "self": {
    "type": "thing.foo",
    "uri": "/foo/123=?drilldown=bar",
    "href": "http://localhost/api/foo/123?drilldown=bar"
  },
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "bar",
      "rev": "foo",
      "type": "thing.bar",
      "uri": "/bar/456",
      "href": "http://localhost/api/bar/456"
    }
  ],
  "_bar": [
    {
      "self": {
        "type": "thing.bar",
        "uri": "/bar/456",
        "href": "http://localhost/api/bar/456"
      },
      "links": [
        {
          ..other link..
        },
        {
          ..other link..
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I'm already using hypermedia links/controls to remove the tight coupling to URIs, but I haven't thought about the "drill down" idea which seems very promising. How could a JSON representation look like?At the moment, each JSON representation of my resources contains a `links` array, each entry is a link object with a`rel` and a `uri` field (similar to your xml example). Should I just add a third field to each link object (e.g. `data`)? Is there any standard?

Comment: The drill down isn't really a rest feature, so there are no standards (at least that I know of).

Comment: There are some proposed standards, such as http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html which I'm using in our applications. It's very close to your example.

Answer (score 4):

**If 95% of all queries want `Foo` as well as `Bar`, then simply return it *inside* of the `Foo` object** when you request a `Foo`.  Simply add a property `bar` (or some other term for the relationship), and put the `Bar` object there.  If the relationship doesn't exist, then use null.

I think you're overthinking this :)

Comment: I shouldn't have come up with that number (95%), it was a mistake, sorry. What I wanted to say was that a large part of requests is interested in both resources at the same time. But there still is a relevant number of requests that are only interested in `Foo`, and since each `Bar` is quite huge in memory (around 3x-4x the size of `Foo`), I don't want to return a `Bar` if a client does not request it explicitly.

Comment: How big are we talking? I doubt that it's going to make *that* much of a difference in transfer time, and I prefer a clean API over speed